# IE11 - flash (.swf) not working when not connected/offline using appcache (webcam.js)

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-11, offline, html5-appcache, webcam.js

we are running webcam.js to take pictures inside a html site. We are also using appcache to provide offline access to all of the files.

Everything works fine in Chrome (43.0.2357.124) regardless of the connection (online/offline). When using the same site in Internet Explorer (11.0.9600.17842) we are expiriencing problems when using the webcam.js to take pictures.

When the device is online, everything works as planned but as soon as the device goes offline, the execution/initialization of the flash plugin seems to fail (only a blank space and when you right click, it says 'could not be loaded). You can see in the network tab inside the developer tools that the webcam.swf has the status '(aborted)'.

The status of the webcam.swf when the device is online is 304 - so it seems that it is loaded from cache, which is fine.

We also created several testcases where we were using several different swf files and a stripped down appcache manifest, but couldn't get it to work inside IE 11 (Windows 8.1). Neither inside the metro or desktop version of the browser. We also tested on 3 different devices, but still no luck.

Any ideas what is causing this problems in IE? Thanks in advance!